# Vestacp php 7.2.* upgrade breaks nginx and php-fpm on Ubuntu Digital Ocean

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-16.04, vesta

I wish to update PHP on Vestacp.

My installation procedure is the following:

```
curl -O https://assets.digitalocean.com/vesta/install-vesta-do.sh

chmod +x install-vesta-do.sh

bash install-vesta-do.sh --force --nginx yes --phpfpm yes --apache no --named yes --remi yes --vsftpd no --proftpd no --iptables yes --fail2ban yes --quota no --exim yes --dovecot yes --spamassassin yes --clamav yes --softaculous no --mysql yes --postgresql no
```

Everything works fine, but once I try to update PHP to 7.2.*, it doesn't work and php-fpm and nginx breaks.

Comment: https://www.mysterydata.com/upgrade-php-5-6-php-7-2-centos-vesta-cp/

Comment: Please provide details. What does the error log says?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.